# what does a[0] indicate(mean) in multidimensional array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm just started studying C language with a book and is not getting bit confused on the part where they discuss pointers and arrays. If there is a multidimensional array(I'll just discuss this array as two-dimensional to be specific) called `a[NUM_ROW][NUM_COLS]`, what does the `a[0]` mean?

The part I was studying had a part concerning "processing the rows of a multidimensional array" and it had example where

```
p = &a[i][0] ;
```

could be written as

```
p = a[i];
```

and the book said `a[i]` is a pointer to the first element in row i.

Then there was a part about "using the name of a multidimensional array as a pointer" where in the case of int `a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS]`, the array name a is not a pointer to `a[0][0]` but a pointer to `a[0]`.

Does `a[0]` have same meaning as the `a[i]` in the first part? I am a bit confused because in the part about "using the name of a multidimensional array as a pointer" the books says array name a is a pointer to an integer array of length NUM_COLS(and a has type `int (*) [NUM_COLS]`

I was wondering if `a[0]` indicate the integer array of length NUM_COLS or a pointer to the first element in row 0. (Or is it the same thing? Maybe since I am a bit new to the concept and confused.)

P.S. the book is chapter 12.4 of C programming(KNK)

Comment: Given `a[n][m]` you can say that `a[0]` is an array of `m` elements (in many contexts, `a[0]` is converted to a pointer to the first element of the array `a[0]`).

Comment: You might like section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: Oh thank you I will check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element. A multidimensional array is basically just an array of arrays, so when you have `int a[NUM_ROW][NUM_COL]`, `a[i]` is the "name" of the i'th row.

So by the above rule, `a[i]` decays to a pointer to the first element of that row, which is `a[i][0]`. To create a pointer we put `&` before the expression, so that's `&a[i][0]`.

And `a` decays to a pointer to the the first element of the 2-dimensional array. Each element of the main array is a row, not an individual integer, so `a` is equivalent to `&a[0]`, not `&a[0][0]`.

The memory location of `a[0]` and `a[0][0]` are the same, the difference is in the *type* of the expression. The type of `a[0][0]` is `int`, but the type of `a[0]` is `int[NUM_COL]`, which will decay to `int *` in many contexts. This is easiest to see by using the `typeof` operator:

```
printf("size of a = %d, size of a[0] = %d, size of a[0][0] = %d\n", sizeof a, sizeof a[0], sizeof a[0][0]);
```

If `NUM_ROW = 5` and `NUM_COL = 10`, this will probably print:

```
size of a = 200, size of a[0] = 40, size of a[0][0] = 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So in paragraph 3 where you said "so a is equivalent to &a[0]", is a[0] the name of the i'th row(or the first element of the 2 dimensional array) and not pointer?

Comment: Yes. Arrays don't decay to pointers when they're the argument of the `&` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's get this out of the way: Arrays and pointers are not one and the same. Array type is a different type. As an example, if you have a pointer `int* ptr`, `++ptr` is perfectly valid (though it might not point to something valid), but if you have an array like `int a[3]`, you may not increment it. But one constraint arrays have is, you may not pass arrays to functions and functions may not return array type. But what happens when you try? What happens is your array is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. That is where the confusion comes from: Arrays are converted to a pointer to their first element when you need a pointer pointing them. Therefore, `ptr = a` would mean `ptr` is now pointing to the first element of `a`.

Now let's assume we have this:

```
int arr[3][3] = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}};
```

What is this exactly? It is an array of arrays. `arr[i]` refers to one of the answers though it usually decays to a pointer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah I think my confusion in pointer and array was probably the main reason for this question..